# Google maps with responsive sidebar

Tags: google-maps

This is a google map that I found in this [link](http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/mundo/2016/02/1742722-foi-uma-vida-dura-diz-adolescente-sueca-resgatada-do-ei-no-iraque.shtml).
 [image]

I would like to know how to implement a responsive side bar like this one:
[image]

And there are another different sidebar
[image]

Does someone know what functionality is this or how to implement it?  Similar to this [example](http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/).
I could not find in [google maps docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)

Comment: Using the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial): [map with sidebar (ported to v3 from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html), [KML based map with sidebar (uses geoxml3)](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_categories_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/nzhistory_net_nzmap_locations_kml.xml), [KML based map with sidebar (uses geoxml-v3)](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_dyasdesigns_com_geoxml_mtrmtrip3.html)

Comment: HI friend, the example you sent is nice but I am looking for the side bar that can be hided. The behavior seems to be like like bootstrap like this http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/

Comment: That's an embedded Google My Maps map (https://www.google.com/mymaps). They used the map editor GUI on that site to make and style the map, and then they chose the "embed on my site" option. You can't modify that code or make it yourself; it's auto-generated by Google on the fly. If you want a map very much like the one above, they're free to make, but you can't add your own JS, HTML or CSS and the styling is limited.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to modify the [example you link to](http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/) to put the marker information sidebar from [the examples I linked to in my comments](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html) in its dynamic sidebar.

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_sidebarToggleMap_bootstrapB.html)

**code snippet:**

```js
// arrays to hold copies of the markers and html used by the side_bar 
// because the function closure trick doesnt work there 
var gmarkers = [];
var map = null;

function initialize() {
  var myWrapper = $("#wrapper");
  $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    myWrapper.one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e) {
      // code to execute after transition ends
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    });
  });
  // create the map
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.907787, -79.359741),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
  });

  // Add markers to the map
  // Set up three markers with info windows 
  // add the points    
  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(43.65654, -79.90138);
  var marker = createMarker(point, "This place", "Some stuff to display in the<br>First Info Window")

  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(43.91892, -78.89231);
  var marker = createMarker(point, "That place", "Some stuff to display in the<br>Second Info Window")

  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(43.82589, -78.89231);
  var marker = createMarker(point, "The other place", "Some stuff to display in the<br>Third Info Window")
}

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
});

// This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window
function myclick(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}

// A function to create the marker and set up the event window function 
function createMarker(latlng, name, html) {
  var contentString = html;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  // save the info we need to use later for the side_bar
  gmarkers.push(marker);
  // add a line to the side_bar html
  var sidebar = $('#side_bar');
  var sidebar_entry = $('<li/>', {
    'html': name,
    'click': function() {
      google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
    },
    'mouseenter': function() {
      $(this).css('color', 'red');
    },
    'mouseleave': function() {
      $(this).css('color', '#999999');
    }
  }).appendTo(sidebar);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#map_canvas,
#wrapper,
#page-content-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.container-fluid,
.row,
.col-lg-12 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
}
/* hamburger menu pseudo element */

.box-shadow-menu {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1.25em;
}
.box-shadow-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0.25em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 0.15em;
  background: black;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25em 0 0 black, 0 0.5em 0 0 black;
}
/* hamburger menu pseudo element gradient */

.gradient-menu {
  padding-left: 1.25em;
  position: relative;
}
.gradient-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0.21em;
  bottom: 0.21em;
  width: 1em;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, black, black 20%, white 20%, white 40%, black 40%, black 60%, white 60%, white 80%, black 80%, black 100%);
}
/* http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Bootstrap-Sidebar-Extension-With-jQuery-CSS-CSS3/ */

/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Simple Sidebar HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

/* Toggle Styles */

.nav-tabs>li {
  float: none;
}
.nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 250px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
}
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -250px;
}
/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
}
.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
  #wrapper {
    padding-left: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav" id="side_bar">
      <li class="sidebar-brand" style="font-weight: bold; color: #999999;">
        <h1>Places</h1>
      </li>
      <hr>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h1>
        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="gradient-menu" id="menu-toggle"></a>
          &nbsp;Map&nbsp;<!-- a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" >Toggle Sidebar</a -->
          </h1>
          <!-- you can use tables or divs for the overall layout -->
          <div id="map_canvas"></div>
          <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
It is an application to create and share customized maps.
I had no time to dig inside, but it seems it was created to help people that are not familiar with code like Maps API.
The name is [My Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/?hl=en_US&app=mp).

There we can create maps and layers.
Layers are in fact the side bar I was looking for.

I found a forum to solve issues related to this appilication
in this [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/maps/category$3Acustom-maps).